# Unable to join a site by voting on question

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, ios-app, login

I just tried to join an Amateur Radio site by voting on the question with no luck.

The joining indicator appears for a long time:

> [image: joining]

Until timeout occurs:

> [image: failed]

Seems I actually joined the site successfully, but the message in app is confusing.

- App Version: 1.6.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed.

When creating a user on a site, the API first creates a lock so it doesn't try creating the same user twice.  Because the API runs on multiple web servers, it stores the lock in Redis.  Unfortunately, the Redis cache it was using has gotten heavily trafficked in recent months and it had to spend a long time waiting for the lock, long enough that your iPad gave up on listening and returned an error.

I've moved the lock to a less busy queue while I clean up the other one.