# Still unable to join a site when voting on a post

Tags: bug, ios-app

This is very similar to the [Unable to join a site by voting on question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296159/219368) problem, but that should have been fixed back then.

Here are the screenshots before the error occurred and if the error itself:

[image: before_error]
[image: error]

Please lmk what extra information I can provide. Thanks for looking into this.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone10,6)
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)